# Why is only MOV allowed for surge suppression according to IEC 60950-1

Tags: mains, legal

IEC 60950-1 prescribes that if a surge suppressor is used in a primary circuit it "shall be a VDR". The document informs that a VDR is sometimes referred to as a "varistor or a metal oxide varistor (MOV)".

It further explicitly states that "gas discharge tubes, carbon blocks or semiconductor devices with non-linear voltage/current characteristics" are not allowed.

Why is this? From what I've read, I'd much rather use a high voltage TVS diode. MOV's seem to have a finite life when subjected to transients.

Edit: As was helpfully pointed out by Spehro, the word is Prescribe, not Proscribe as I initially wrote :-).

Comment: Glad to see you did read my link :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prescribes VDRs, and proscribes the other stuff.

Speculation here- maybe VDRs, of the **approved** persuasion, are guaranteed to die a peaceful smouldering black death. Approved TVS parts are probably nonexistent and gas discharge tubes tend to arc (well they're supposed to).

Comment: English isn't my native language. I have to admit I didn't realize those were two separate words. One little letter can make a difference :-) .

Comment: @avl_sweden Yes, makes them into opposites. We even have words such *cleave* that are their own opposite or *inflammable* and *flammable* that look like opposites but mean the same thing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Speculation here too: it matters, if in death it becomes short or break. One is safer.

Comment: MOVs generally go short first, then burn up and go open.